# Cannot create Access tables through SQL view

Tags: sql, ms-access, syntax

I'm trying to create 3 access tables in SQL view on Microsoft Access but whenever I try to execute it, I receive the following error. 'Syntax Error in CREATE TABLE statement'.

Please find my code below.

```
CREATE TABLE Book (
Book_ID int,
Book_Title varchar (30),
PRIMARY KEY (Book_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Users (
User_ID int,
User_Name varchar (30), 
PRIMARY KEY (User_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Borrows (
User_ID int,
Book_ID int,
B_ID int,
PRIMARY KEY(B_ID),
FOREIGN KEY(User_ID) REFERENCES Users(User_ID),
FOREIGN KEY(Book_ID) REFERENCES Book(Book_ID)
);

INSERT INTO Book VALUES (101, 'The Hobbit'), (102, 'To Kill a Mockingbird');

INSERT INTO Users VALUES (1, 'Stephen'), (2, 'Tom'), (3,' Eric');

INSERT INTO Borrows VALUES (3, 102, 1), (1, 101, 2);
```

Appreciate any feedback I can get, have a good day.

Comment: You also can ONLY put one full create statement in the query builder at a time - multiple statements are not supported. As noted, you have to use correct table create syntax. So the syntax to create a table for Oracle, MySQL, SQL server or Access are all different from different vendors - you have to use ms-access syntax for the table create commands. Below answer has a link on the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Your first `CREATE TABLE` executed flawlessly from the query designer in Access 2010.  However my preference is to include the `PRIMARY KEY` constraint as part of the field definition:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Book (
Book_ID int PRIMARY KEY,
Book_Title varchar (30)
);
```

That variation also executed successfully.

I suspect you have at least 2 issues to resolve:

1. Access does not allow you to execute more than one SQL statement at a time (as [Heinzi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68793192/77335) and [Albert mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68793123/cannot-create-access-tables-through-sql-view/68793468#comment121577381_68793123)).  You must execute them one at a time.
2. In Access, `INSERT ... VALUES` can only be used to add one row at a time.  Revise your inserts accordingly.

IOW, split the first one into 2 statements which you then execute individually:

```sql
-- INSERT INTO Book VALUES (101, 'The Hobbit'), (102, 'To Kill a Mockingbird');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (101, 'The Hobbit');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (102, 'To Kill a Mockingbird');
```

Then split and execute the remaining inserts similarly.

Answer (score 0):

Your code example use SQL Server (T-SQL) syntax, not MS Access syntax.

The syntax for Access' `CREATE TABLE` statement is documented here:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/create-table-statement-microsoft-access-sql

The most obvious differences seem to be there is no `varchar` type and that `PRIMARY KEY` needs a constraint name if specified in an extra line. There might be more, see the article and its examples for details. I also suggest that you submit your statements one-by-one, instead of submitting a complete `;`-separated batch; I'm not sure Access queries even support the latter.